# How to call a PHP function from within a PHP if/else statement in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

This is my first time posting a question here, and I truly appreciate any suggestions that might be able to help me.

I'm trying to call a Wordpress PHP function from within a PHP if else statement, to get it to display the more recent date when comparing get_the_modified_date() and get_the_date().

Here is my code:

```
if ( $date1 > $date2 ) { 
echo 'This page was last updated on <span class="date updated"><?php echo get_the_modified_date(\'F j, Y\');?></span>.<hr /></div>';
} else {
echo 'This page was last updated on <span class="date updated"><?php echo get_the_date(\'F j, Y\');?></span>.<hr /></div>';
}
?>
```

Any thoughts on how to get this to parse correctly?  I tried commenting out the ('F j, Y') with \ but it doesn't display the date at all -- all that is displayed is:

"This page was last updated on ."

Thank you all!

Comment: Move the PHP outside of the echo.

Answer (score 2):

The way you have it typed, it will actualy echo the `<?php ...` as raw text.

Try this:

```
echo 'This page was last updated on <span class="date updated">' . get_the_date(\'F j, Y\') . '</span>.<hr /></div>';
```

In the above, each `.` will append the contents together, String, function with String result, and String, forming one long String.

Answer (score 2):

Basic PHP:

```
<?php
echo "foo <?php echo 'bar'; ?>";
```

You cannot embed PHP-in-PHP like that. This echo command will dump out the literal text

```
foo <?php echo 'bar'; ?>
```

If you want to execute your code, you'd need

```
echo 'This page blah blah', the_date(...), 'etc...';
```